# Process,Kill() Not Working

Tags: c#, windows, service, process, kill-process

I'm trying to make a service, that every 1000milliseconds(1 Second) Kills any process with the name Skype. I'm 100% sure I have coded it all correctly, everything is working, logging etc. But killing the process is not.

```
    private System.Timers.Timer _timer;
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(100);
            _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;
            _timer.Enabled = true;
            if (!EventLog.SourceExists("MYTESTSERVICE"))
                EventLog.CreateEventSource("MYTESTSERVICE", "MYTESTSERVICE LOG");
            //_timer.Start();
            Process[] p = Process.GetProcessesByName("Skype");
            foreach (Process proc in p)
            {

                proc.Kill();
                proc.WaitForExit();
                EventLog.WriteEntry("User Tried To Start Skype! Closed.", EventLogEntryType.Warning);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry(String.Format("WcfServiceHostTest \n Exception Message: {0}\nTrace: {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace), EventLogEntryType.Error);
        }
    }
```

I am currently not using the timer, but instead testing it upon service startup. If Skype is running, the process is not killed. I even tried notepad, and it did not kill that either. I have done research on this, but have not found an answer.

Any help is appreciated!

- Seb

Comment: Are you running in elevated mode/with Admin privileges?

Comment: I have a batch file that uninstalls the service, then installs it and runs it. This is all done in administrative mode. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Are there elements in p? If yes: Is the execution going past proc.WaitForExit()?

Comment: Originally I tried it with just getAllProcesses. And it returned everything(I printed it to event logger). With skype, I am most likely there should be elements in it. And no, it does not get passed WaitForExit().

Comment: It would be nice if I got a reason for the downvote? AM I doing something stupid or?

Comment: @FunkyPeanut do you suggest anything?

Comment: Try stepping through with a debugger and report back the results please. It often happens that one makes assumptions about the code that hold not true because one misses some little piece.

Comment: @FunkyPeanut I can't seem to debug it in visual studio because it is a windows service. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the taskkill:

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "taskkill",
        Arguments = $"/im skype.exe /f /t",
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        UseShellExecute = false
    }).WaitForExit();
```